# Schedule a Job to execute certain times per day with Quartz.Net

Tags: quartz-scheduler, batch-processing, jobs, quartz.net

I am kinda new on Quartz.Net and it satisfy most of my needs for Job management.

But due to other necesities, I've got the following question:

I know It's possible to schedule the specific time for a Daily Execution (I.E. Executes Everyday at 12:45pm) but, what if I want to execute a process more than one certain time?

I.E.
1st time: 12:00
2nd time: 17:00
3rd time: 23:00

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve arbitrary executions in this case is to create three separate triggers. Three cron triggers with following patterns should do the job:

```
0 0 12 * * ?
0 0 17 * * ?
0 0 23 * * ?
```

You can have as many triggers as you want for a single job. But if you find it be more like an interval you can also check other trigger types spiced up with calendars for exclusion/inclusion.